# jquery - slideshow buttons

Tags: jquery, css, slideshow

I have problem that I'm trying to figure out a solution for it from a long time.
Here's my slideshow: http://jsfiddle.net/Jtec5/33/
 
Codes: CSS:

```
#slideshow {
    margin: 50px auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 240px;
    height: 240px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
#slideshow > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
}

#slideshow img {
    max-width:240px;
    max-height:240px;
}

ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
ul li {
    float:left;
    border-radius:10px;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    border:1px solid white;
    background:grey;
}
ul li.active {
    background:black;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <div>
        <img src="http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5224/5658667829_2bb7d42a9c_m.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5230/5638093881_a791e4f819_m.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://gillespaquette.ca/images/stack-icon.png" />
    </div>
</div>
<ul></ul>
```

Jquery:

```
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

var maxindex = $('#slideshow > div').length;

var index = 0
var interval = 3 * 1000; // 3 seconds
var timerJob = setInterval(traverseSlideShow, interval);

function traverseSlideShow() {
    console.log("current index: " + index);

    $('#slideshow > div')
        .stop()
        .fadeOut(1000);
    $('#slideshow > div').eq(index)
        .stop()
        .fadeIn(1000);

    $('ul li').removeClass('active');
    $('ul li:eq(' + index + ')').addClass('active');
    index = (index < maxindex - 1) ? index + 1 : 0;

}

for (var i = 0; i < maxindex; i++) {
    $('ul').append('<li class="' + (i == 0 ? 'active' : '') + '"></li>');
}

$(document).on('click', 'ul li', function () {
    index = $(this).index();
    traverseSlideShow();
    clearInterval(timerJob);
    timerJob = setInterval(traverseSlideShow, interval);
});
```

I have circle buttons `<ul>` in the slideshow that takes you to the photo it's related with, the problem begins if you click on this button much times, you can see the picture pause for very short time and continue to appear, every extra click pauses the photo for short time from appearing.

Comment: and who should it be?

Comment: What do you mean by that? I think it's jquery issue if I understood your question correctly

Comment: I ask how do you expect to be? because for me your question is not clear, just that.

Comment: I think it's clear, you just have to click on one of the buttons much much times (spam click) and you can see the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a `if` statement to check if the `this` index in the click is the same as the image being showed. And in that case `return false`.

```
if (last_index == $(this).index()) {
    return false
}
```

### Demo [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/PQ9uY/)